# Android: Disable text selection in a webview

Tags: android, webview

I am using a webview to present some formatted stuff in my app. For some interaction (which are specific to certain dom elements) I use javascript and `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`. Now, I want to recognize a long touch. Unfortunately, `onLongTouch`, in Android 2.3 the handles for text selection are displayed.

How can I turn off this text selection *without* setting the `onTouchListener` and return true? (Then, the interaction with the "website" doesn't work anymore.

Comment: For those curious to handle (e.g. disable) all touch events through a custom `View.OnTouchListener`, [see this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853794/disable-webview-touch-events-in-android).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out!! This is how you can implement your own longtouchlistener. In the function longTouch you can make a call to your javascript interface.

```
var touching = null;
$('selector').each(function() {
    this.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        touching = window.setTimeout(longTouch, 500, true);
    }, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.clearTimeout(touching);
    }, false);
});

function longTouch(e) {
    // do something!
}
```

This works.

Comment: My problem remains: The `event.preventDefault()` call in the touchstart event also prevents the normal cursor mode input/selection (on html textinput elements).

Comment: that is true... Maybe switching off all long touch events on the android layer and removing the preventDefaults works?

Comment: the behaviour is confusing me.. returning true for every onTouch event seems to work, but when I only select certain (long) move and down events to skip further propagation, I run into states, where I do not get any event until text selection is cancelled (e.g.) input element changed.. text selection seems also be triggered between the down and the (future) up event. maybe I am missing another event type where I can cancel it..

Comment: I've found that this breaks any scrolling in the browser. For example, if you put your finger on the `selector` element and try to scroll up and down, nothing will happen.

Comment: @EMMERICH, I ran into same problem, it broke scrolling. Is there any solution to prevent text selection in native way?

Comment: Thanks for this info - I was having a different problem - trying to prevent android from popping up a selector box while the html selector was disabled by my code (using logic, not the disabled state), and your method of catching 'touchstart' did the trick

Answer (score 145):

This worked for me

```
mWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return true;
    }
});
mWebView.setLongClickable(false);
```

I have not tested, if you don't want the vibration caused by the long click, you can try this:

```
mWebView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
```

Comment: That still produce a small vibration (but no contextual action bar).

Comment: mWebView.setLongClickable(false); does not make any different, but setting long click listener and passing true from onLongClick() method worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, but I didn't need the last line "mWebView.setLongClickable(false);"

Comment: `mWebView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> true);`
`mWebView.setLongClickable(false);`

Comment: This is working fine but if we double tap on the content in a text field ,selection& copy options are enabled. How to disable this?

Comment: Worked for me for a Crash Bug fix in Lollipop Android Versions. Thanks.

Comment: Not working for me, text keeps getting selected upon short click.

Answer (score 44):

Setting webkit css property `-webkit-user-select` to `none` would solve the problem.

Example CSS to disable selection:

```
* {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the best solution to prevent selection because it is cross-platform.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in all versions of Android. It _should_ be the best solution, but it isn't :/

Comment: *:not(input):not(textarea) {
    webkit-user-select: none;
}

Comment: Thanks alot, in order to get it to work with android I changed it to
'{
  webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}'

Answer (score 6):

It appears that cut/paste via long press is turned off if you used

```
    articleView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){...})
```

See https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31484

So if you are using setChromeClient and you WANT to have long click to start copy/paste, the do the following:

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        [.... other overrides....]

        // @Override
        // https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31484
        // If you DO NOT want to start selection by long click,
        // the remove this function
        // (All this is undocumented stuff...)
        public void onSelectionStart(WebView view) {
            // By default we cancel the selection again, thus disabling
            // text selection unless the chrome client supports it.
            // view.notifySelectDialogDismissed();
        }

    });
```

Comment: I need to have the copy/paste feature in my webview. I used setWebChromeClient to use onProgressChanged method for progress bar updates. This disabled the copy/paste feature. Adding the onSelectionStart method enabled copy/paste again. Thanks a lot for this hidden gem!

Comment: This method isn't in the API, what are you guys talking about? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html

Comment: This also confuses me, what Android system are you talking about?

Comment: They are referring to a "hidden" API method: https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31484#c15  hence why it does not show up in the API docs for WebChromeClient class.

Comment: This workaround only works until SDK 2.3.7 r1. For newer SDK you can't use WebChromeClient or don't use Copy/Paste on 2.3.x mobiles. See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.java/ and http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.java/

Comment: Would this also help with long clicking on links in order to open them in the default web browser?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only option is to set `onTouchListener` and write your own code to detect long-click. Then return `true` if it's a long-click and `false` otherwise.

Comment: But I want to implement a longclick listener in javascript as well. By overriding the onTouchListener I would turn off all long clicks on the view. How can it be, that one can not turn off text selection? I think this is a pretty basic thing to want to do.

Comment: Got it. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923782/disable-the-text-highlighting-magnifier-on-touch-hold-on-mobile-safari-webkit

Comment: does not seem to have any effect in android.

Comment: but with android 4.4 default selection also coming

Comment: this would disable scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to subclass WebView and Override performLongClick as bellow:

```
public class AdvanceWebView extends WebView {
   //Add constructors...
   @Override
   public boolean performLongClick() {
   return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin i found the following to work:

```
webView.isLongClickable = false
```