# Web app running on Android: how to prevent text selection?

Tags: android

I have a mobile app (HTML, Javascript) that is supposed to run on iPhone and Android smartphones.
To make it look more like a real app and prevent accidential text selection, I'm cathing the `touchStart` end `touchEnd` events and handle them. This prevents text selection just fine.
On Android however, it seems to be completely ignored; text selection is possible.
Is there a defined way in Android to prevent the user from selecting text from a web app?

René

Comment: Is it a app in a browser or a native app with a webview?

Comment: It is an app running in Android's browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use WebKit's CSS selector this. Just apply this to "html, body" or your element on the webapp.

```
-webkit-user-select: none
```

http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-user-select

Comment: Does not work.
Those work on iPhone, but not Android:
user-select: none; 
-webkit-user-select: none; 
-moz-user-select: none; 
-khtml-user-select: none;

Comment: Wow - that's baffling. Have you tried a variation of this to get what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107651/android-disable-text-selection-in-a-webview

Comment: Yes. It causes so many unwanted sideeffects that I don't find it very useful. Android browsers are very weird beasts...even Google's own sites don't really work with them. :-)