# How to disable text selection in a webview in Android?

Tags: android, webview, textselection, disabled-control, long-click

My application playing `HTML` promotions in `WebView`, Html promotions having **text** so if user press **long click** android standard dialog appear `Copy/Share/Find/Web Search`, so is there any option to disable text selection dialog for webview ?

Help me on the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107651/android-disable-text-selection-in-a-webview

The first aswer with javascript works perfect.

Answer (score 15):

You need to do this way:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

webView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          return true;
      }
    });
webView.setLongClickable(false);

// Below line prevent vibration on Long click
webView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
```

Hope this will help you.