# Android: how to disable text selection in WebView for Android 4.0+?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820708/disabling-text-selection)

I'm building a phonegap based app and I'd like to not allow text selection by default while long touch was happening. I've looked for days all over the SO, the answers all failed to work, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107651/android-disable-text-selection-in-a-webview) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995210/disabling-user-selection-in-uiwebview). The auto text selection only happened on Android 4.0+ for me.

1. The simplest solution that setting '-webkit-user-select: none;' didn't work (however it worked for iOS UIWebview)
2. I only want to disable this single feature with keeping touch events on, so no overriding touch events.

Any idea about this problem specific for Android 4.0+? Thanks in advance.