# How to disable copy paste,spellcheck,autocomplete in Cordova Android application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

How to disable copy paste,spellcheck,autocomplete in Cordova Android application? At time text typed by user gets autocompleted.

Comment: there are some css rules you can add to disable  copying text -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: @MuhammadUsman - I have tried restricting it by using jQuery 'paste' and trimming extra characters but a lot of manipulation is required as I have to validate lot of characters. It's a banking app. Passing any invalid data means dirty payload hence server rejects it completely

Answer (score 4):

```
 $('input').bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Please try this code if not use contextmenu functionality in your app otherwise contextmenu functionality will be stop working

Answer (score 2):

```
 **Use below code:**
 <style type="text/css">
 *:not(input):not(textarea) {
 -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when           long-press on a link */
  }       
  </style>

 **If you want Disable only anchor button tag use this.**
      a {-webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of      UIWebView */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when   long-press on a link */
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Tasos says in his comment is valid, if you want **all** user selection disabled in the app you can use the answer from this question: [Disabling text selection in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820708/disabling-text-selection-in-phonegap)

> I looked all over for help on this. This finally worked for me.
>
> ```
> public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>         super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
>
>         super.appView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
>
>             public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
>                 return true;
>             }
>         });
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The setOnClickListener is what does the magic. Make sure you put this
>   AFTER your call to super.loadUrl.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have idea about Javascript and Cordova but in Android code you can try this.

**Required API level 11 or above.**

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Returning **false** from **onCreateActionMode(ActionMode, Menu)** will prevent the action mode from being started(Select All, Cut, Copy and Paste actions).

Answer (score 0):

So, i don't know, if your suggested answers are working. He wanted to know, how he can deactivate this inside a Cordova application. For what did you post native code than?

Normal `input` field without deactivation would look like this:

```
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
```

To deactivate those things, just edit it, that it looks like this:

```
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
```

Hope that helped!