# Webview Text selection handles issue

Tags: android

I have applied transparent image to android system default text selection handles  to hide them using this code in theme

```
<item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right</item>
```

this code is working fine for above API 14 but it's not working in API 14.
what should i do to hide default text selection handles in API 14 & below.

Comment: see if below post helps !!! [Disabling Text Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820708/disabling-text-selection-in-phonegap/11872686#11872686)

Comment: @sandip - I am working on native android development. Not on Phonegap