# How can I disable copy , paste and select toolbar , from a webview inside Android application

Tags: android, webview

How can I disable copy, paste and select toolbar from a webview inside Android application?

I am making an application that actually "webview" a website that work on Javascripts and Jquery.

So I am wondering if I can disable the copy paste toolbar.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107651/android-disable-text-selection-in-a-webview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disables all touch events on a WebView

```
mWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    return true;
}
});
mWebView.setLongClickable(false);
```

Comment: but double tap on the text box gives the context menu.