# How to disable sharing from app selected text

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext, android-sharing

I have a `WebView` and some `EditText`s in my android app. When I select text I have an option to share this text.
Now I want to **disable this text sharing feature** in my whole app.
What is the most reliable way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005852/how-can-i-disable-copy-paste-and-select-toolbar-from-a-webview-inside-androi

Answer (score 3):

For a web view there is a good method `[setDisabledActionModeMenuItems][1]` but it is available for android sdk 24+ only.

I used reflection like this

```
  private void disableSelectedTextOptions() {
    // TODO Method setDisabledActionModeMenuItems should be called directly after project will be migrated to SDK 24+
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) return;
    Method method = null;
    try {
      method = webSettings.getClass().getMethod("setDisabledActionModeMenuItems", int.class);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }
    try {
      method.invoke(webSettings,
          /*WebSettings.MENU_ITEM_SHARE*/ 1 |
          /*WebSettings.MENU_ITEM_WEB_SEARCH*/ 2 |
          /*WebSettings.MENU_ITEM_PROCESS_TEXT*/ 4);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

For and EditText I used this approach to remove "Share" (and "Translate"):

```
public static void removeShareOption(TextView tv){
    tv.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            menu.removeItem(/*android.R.id.shareText*/0x01020035);
            menu.removeItem(/* Translate */0);
            return true;
        }

        @Override public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
}
```