# Stop 'set as wallpaper' on image long press / click in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have made a web-app that runs within a webview on my android tablet. I have been able to incorporate a long press event to make something happen, but something if there is an image android shows the 'set as wallpapaer / save as ' dialog for the image. Can I disable this?

Thanking you

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413683/disabling-the-context-menu-on-long-taps-on-android

Comment: @keune - i think it will disable my long press code too...let me test now

Comment: ok this worked for me for the image set as wallpaper and text selection problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107651/android-disable-text-selection-in-a-webview

Answer (score 0):

Alright the solution by 'Samuel' solved the image 'set as wallpaper' dialog appearrin problem and also the 'text selection' feature got disabled on long clicks!

[Android: Disable text selection in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107651/android-disable-text-selection-in-a-webview)