# Simulation html text selection in android

Tags: javascript, android, html, range, textselection

I need to simulate selecting text in a HTML page from android browsers. Android has a special selector in a web page. My HTML page does not detect a selection of text as the browser would have a PC. How I can simulate this selection of text using javascript, jquery, etc.

When I try to select text in android browser. This detects it as a text selection system itself and not as a normal selection as a PC and a  normal browser. How I detect android browsers and how I can fix the text selection?

Comment: I do not know if could deselect android system text with javascript and then detect that is left down for "x" seconds, start selecting text and finally stop when the user lifts the finger

Comment: I found this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107651/android-disable-text-selection-in-a-webview] that may help getit, now only need to simulate selecting text with the positions or elemnts. I would appreciate if someone can help me develop wants this topic

Comment: This could also help. **var range = document.createRange();**
 In order to insert it into the document we need to define its start and end points through the thoughtfully provided **setStart() and setEnd()** methods.