# How to disable long click on WebView in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to disable the long click on webView so I cant select the text in it, and I use three ways to do that but nothing work:

```
1) android:longClickable="false"

2) webView.setLongClickable(false);

3) webView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

So any help please.

Answer (score 14):

To disable long clicks you need to first enable long click `setLongClickable(true);` then the `setOnLongClickListener`, and return nothing:

```
webview.setLongClickable(true);
webview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return true;
        }
    });
```

If you only need to disable text selection it's better to add the following CSS to your webpage and it will disable text selection:

```
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Check the Mozilla documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, as shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12793740/5035343

```
mWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    return true;
}
});
mWebView.setLongClickable(false);
```

And to remove the viberation caused by the long click, you can try this.

```
mWebView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   public void SelectText(View v) {
        try {
            KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ESCAPE, 0, 0);
            shiftPressEvent.dispatch(v);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
```

or :

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent "ACTION_DOWN") {
    try {
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,0,0);
        shiftPressEvent.dispatch(webview);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
webView.setOnLongClickListener(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This method is useful for me, Check it may be help you guys.**

1) Just use this `webView.setLongClickable(false);`

2) use in html with css:

```
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

3) replace body tag with this in html `<body oncontextmenu="return false;">`

Answer (score 0):

use this for kotlin

```
binding.webViewId.setOnLongClickListener(OnLongClickListener { true })
```

or

```
webViewId.setOnLongClickListener(OnLongClickListener { true })
```

Answer (score 0):

This so far working with me

```
webView.setOnLongClickListener { _ -> true }
```