# How to disable user text selection in WebView [React-Native]

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, react-native, textselection

I'm trying to figure out how to disable text selection while in a React-Native WebView for my ios app. Using the css style `user-select` set to `none` on the site doesn't seem to be working while using a device or simulator but it does work in a browser. Is there a way to disable this using the React-Native WebView or do I need to use some native code to achieve this?

Using React-Native 0.30, iOS 9-10

Answer (score 2):

I was able to disable zooming, text selection and other pointer events on the React Native side, by wrapping `WebView` in a `View` and setting a few props:

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
  <WebView
    source={{ uri: webviewUrl }}
    scrollEnabled={false}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: After adding this, it is disabling all webview touches. Is there any way to disable only long press to avoid the copy-select-paste option?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are accessing a particular url on the webview in react native, then in the url, you can use the following tricks:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<div style="font-size:80%;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function absorbEvent_(event) {
      var e = event || window.event;
      e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      e.returnValue = false;
      return false;
    }

    function preventLongPressMenu(node) {
      node.ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
    }

    function init() {
      preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementByTagName('body img'));
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    *:not(input):not(textarea) {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
        -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */

    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="init()"  >


TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>TEST<br>

</body>
```

The above will disable text selection, but it allows other functions such as "click". (it works in both iOS and android devices)

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.38/docs/webview.html#webview) does not mention this, so I would go with native implementation, which is easier than it might seem. You just have to re-implement [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Views/RCTWebView.m) [files](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/webview/ReactWebViewManager.java) (and maybe some others) in a native module that includes the options you want, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12793740/2628463) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6051172/2628463).

Maybe this package can also help you implement your module: https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-webview-android

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Please try.

```
* {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what it does?

Answer (score 0):

I found that add body {user-select: none} can resolve the issue.

```html
body {user-select: none}
```