# How to disable text selection in a webview in android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview, android-jetpack

I want to disable the text selection in android webview and am using Jetpack compose

```
AndroidView(factory = {
                WebView(it).apply {
                    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    )
                    this.isLongClickable = false
                    webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    webViewClient = object: WebViewClient(){
                        override fun onPageStarted(
                            view: WebView, url: String,
                            favicon: Bitmap?) {
                            onShowProgressBar.invoke()
                        }

                        override fun onPageFinished(
                            view: WebView, url: String) {
                            onShowProgressBar.invoke()
                        }
                    }

                    loadUrl(url)
                }
            }, update = {
                it.loadUrl(url)
            })
```

**Note:** I tried with **isLongClickable = false** still its not working

Comment: have you tried other solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5107651/3585796)? using WebView in compose shouldn't be any different

Comment: will  a DisableSelection composable work here?