# How to get rid of the magnifier bubble when dragging or holding down a finger in iOS browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

[image: bubble image]

I’m making a canvas based browser game and I can’t seem to get rid of this text magnifier bubble popping up occasionally when I drag my finger around. I’ve tried `Webkit-touch-callout:none;` but it doesn’t seem to work.

Any ways to disable this? Driving me mad.

Comment: `user-select: none;`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either. I try it on the canvas itself, as well as all the parent containers but nope, still appears.